# How to get the nearest face to a surface in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

There is a surface defined by a plane object (outlined in screenshot) and a mesh with two faces: 0 and 1 (wire view).

[image]

**I'd like to get face 0 as nearest to this surface**, because 0's center is basically a point in surface. But GN ignores this logic and relies on distance to surface's center, thus giving me face 1.

What is the best approach to get right data, considering randomly rotated surface?

[image]

Comment: did u try just sample nearest?